# Corine Landcover Change Layer Legend

Tags: qgis, legend, land-cover

I downloaded a Corine Land Cover Change Product (CHA 2006-2012) in raster format and opened it in QGIS. The values are between 1 and 44 but I couldn't find a legend that shows which raster values represent which change from which class to which class.

How can I find a legend for changes?

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?  In recent versions, the raster attribute tables that are delivered with the CLC data are directly supported so the CLC classes are symbolized by name.  You can also open the layer properties - symbology tab and select paletted/unique values, click  the advancd options button on the right (just shown as "...") and load the colour map from the "LEGEND/clc_legend_qgis.txt" file that is included with the CLC download.

Comment: Note the values don't show change, they just show which of the standard 44 CLC classes a pixel is if that pixel has changed between those years. To find what that change was, you compare class from the 2012 raster (`U2012_CHA0612_12_V2020_20u1.tif`) to the 2006 raster (`U2012_CHA0612_06_V2020_20u1.tif`).